# Update Birth and death rates in an SIR model

Tags: netlogo

i would like to simulate the disease spread using agent base model by using NetLogo software.
how to Update Birth and death rates in an SIR model.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point you could try the  http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/SimpleBirthRates
that has a method reproduce which adjusts the fertility of the different populations

```
to reproduce
  ask turtles
  [
    ifelse color = red
    [
      set fertility floor red-fertility
      set fertility-remainder red-fertility - (floor red-fertility)
    ]
    [
      set fertility floor blue-fertility
      set fertility-remainder blue-fertility - (floor blue-fertility)
    ]
    ifelse (random-float 100) < (100 * fertility-remainder)
      [ hatch fertility + 1 [ wander ]]
      [ hatch fertility     [ wander ]]
  ]
end
```

For the SIR model see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIR_model#The_SIR_model

You probably want three different populations blue(S susceptible), red(I infectious), and green(R recovered). You want to change the code so that you change `beta I S` blues into reds and change `nu I` reds into greens. `beta` and `nu` are model parameters. It might be easier to start by killing and hatching equal numbers of blues and reds.

The following code implements this. I have three different sets of turtles, initially many more blue than the other colours. The main part happens in the `reproduce` which turns blues to reds:

```
ifelse color = blue
[
  if (random-float 100) < (beta * red-count * blue-count ) / 1000000
    [set color red]
]
```

and reds to greens

```
      ifelse color = red
      [
        if (random-float 100) < (nu * red-count ) / 10000
          [set color green]
      ]
```

The full code is. You need to add sliders for `beta` and `nu`, add a line in the graph for `green-count` and a monitor for `green-count`. The numbers have been chosen by guess work which seem to show a good effect.

```
globals
[
  red-count            ; population of red turtles
  blue-count           ; population of blue turtles
  green-count          ; population of green turtles
]

turtles-own
[

]

to setup
  clear-output
  setup-experiment
end

to setup-experiment
  cp ct
  clear-all-plots
  reset-ticks
  crt carrying-capacity
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor         ; randomize turtle locations
    ifelse who < (carrying-capacity / 10)  ; start out with equal numbers of reds and blues
      [ set color red ]
      [ 
        ifelse who < (2 * carrying-capacity / 10)  ; start out with equal numbers of reds and blues
      [ set color green ]
      [ set color blue ]
 ]
    set size 2                            ; easier to see
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  reproduce
  tick
end

to reproduce
  ask turtles
  [
    ifelse color = blue
    [
      if (random-float 100) < (beta * red-count * blue-count ) / 1000000
        [set color red]
    ]
    [
      ifelse color = red
      [
        if (random-float 100) < (nu * red-count ) / 10000
          [set color green]
      ]
      [

      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```